# Can i flash indian rom in korean galaxy note?

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, rom-flashing, samsung-galaxy-note

I got the Samsung Galaxy Note shv-e160l (Korean version) as a gift, running the stock ICS 4.0. I want to flash official indian JB ROM (of the GT-N7000) on it. Is it possible if I root my device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, do not try to do this, or you will brick your device. SHV-E160L and GT-N7000 have completely different processors (Qualcomm Snapdragon APQ8060 for SHV-E160L, and Samsung S5PC210 for GT-N7000); e.g., see [this comparison](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=pdacomparer&id1=3100&id2=3343&id3=3288&id4=3568&id5=3569&id6=3290).

There are some custom ROMs for SHV-E160L in the [xda-developers section for AT&T Samsung Galaxy Note I717](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1496) (this device is closer to SHV-E160L, but also not 100% compatible, so look carefully and use only ROMs which are made for SHV-E160L).

Comment: Thanks man but i want something to be clarified."This device is closer to SHV-E 160L" does that mean if i can't find any custom roms i can flash a rom for the AT&T version on my device ? Is the chance of bricking low ?

Comment: The problem is that there is currently no special section for the SHV-E160 series of devices on XDA-developers forums, therefore discussion and ROM releases for SHV-E160 are in the section for I717, which has some common hardware with E160 devices, but is not exactly the same. So you will find ROMs for SHV-E160 and I717 in the same forum, but this does **not** mean that ROMs for I717 will work on E160 series devices. Use only ROMs which are explicitly described as compatible with your device model.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't run the Indian ROM. Both are different chipsets, and forcing it might brick your device.

Many users requested the SHW-M180S Firmware. I have uploaded it [here](http://www.4shared.com/get/Q0Sk-qiC/IceCreamSandwich_M180S_Stable_.html).

It is **only** for the SHW-M180S tablet.

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to download ROMs from dodgy file-sharing sites. Only install ROMs from sources you trust to be genuine.